# Get Table Name From DbEntityEntry (Code-First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Simple: How do I get the mapped table name from a DbEntityEntry object? I'm inside a class that extends DbContext. I've seen examples for ObjectContext but doesn't apply to CF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in another answer, the table name can be obtained using the IObjectContextAdapter

```
 private string GetTableName(DbEntityEntry ent)
        {
            ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext;
            Type entityType = ent.Entity.GetType();

            if (entityType.BaseType != null && entityType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
                entityType = entityType.BaseType;

            string entityTypeName = entityType.Name;

            EntityContainer container =
                objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
            string entitySetName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                                    where meta.ElementType.Name == entityTypeName
                                    select meta.Name).First();
            return entitySetName;
        }
```

The above code also tests for proxies. Hope this helps someone else who comes to this link as I assume the original poster solved this a long time ago.

Comment: This gets the entity name and not the table name, just FYI.

Comment: @PhilSandler you are right, how can I get the table name?

Comment: See here for how to get the table name http://romiller.com/2014/04/08/ef6-1-mapping-between-types-tables/
(assuming EF 6.1)

Comment: Used @Quails4Eva 's suggestion, works for me on 6.4.4, except that I need to use `ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType())` to get actual type from EntityEntry for `.Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == ...)`. the way described in the blog might return a proxy type generated by EF, then the `Single()` fails.

Answer (score 8):

I found a cleaner way at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) to get rid of the proxy name.

```
private string GetTableName(DbEntityEntry ent)
{
     return ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entry.Entity.GetType()).Name;
}
```

Comment: thanks I had: return entry.Entity.GetType().Name.Split('_')[0];

Comment: This returns the name of the type, not the name of the table, as configured by [Table("someOtherName")]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get the `ObjectContext` from the `DbContext` (by casting it to `IObjectContextAdapter`) and use the examples you've seen.

Answer (score -1):

On [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) you can find the documentation for DbContext, there you can see that it implements IObjectContextAdapter explicitly, so cast your DbContext-deriving Context to IObjectContextAdapter and use the ObjectContext property.

Comment: And how do I get the entity name?